# creating several records from one, based on a numerical value stored in a field of the source record

Tags: postgresql, query

In a PostgreSQL db, I have a table with a numerical field, among others

In such field, some natural numbers are stored and they represent the number of occurrences of something

like this, roughly

```
record1....3
record2....5
record3....1
record4....2
```

I'd like to create a view that has 3 records created from record1, 5 records created from record2, one record created from reocord3 and 2 records created form record4

is this possible ?

How would I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly but let's assume you've got one field with occurrence count :

```sql
create table test_object as select occurrence from  generate_series(1,10) as occurences;
```

Then you can generate as many records as in occurs column this way :

```sql
select 
  test_object.*,
  item 
from test_object 
join generate_series(1,test_object.occurs) as item on true;
```

Here generate_series will drive your rows creation with the upper bound tied to occurs field.